# in-app purchase UI did not updated

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am implementing the inapp purchase using version 3. I have setup successfully. But my problem is that when we buy item the UI does not updated any how. Here is my code

```
  try
    {
      mHelper=new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
      mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);
      mHelper.startSetup(onIabSetupFinishedListener);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      ShowDailog.Show(this, e.getMessage(), "ok");
    }

   abHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener onIabSetupFinishedListener=new     OnIabSetupFinishedListener() 
{

 @Override
 public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) 
{
if(result.isFailure())
{
complain("Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result);
   return;
}
            //complain("success " + result);
            //mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(queryInventoryFinishedListener);
        }
    };


IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener queryInventoryFinishedListener=new QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) 
        {
            if (result.isFailure()) 
            {
                complain("Failed to query inventory: " + result);
                return;
            }
            if(inventory.hasPurchase(ITEM_SKU));
            {
                mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU), onConsumeFinishedListener);
            }
        }
    };
    IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener onConsumeFinishedListener=new OnConsumeFinishedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) 
        {
             if (result.isSuccess()) 
             {
                            updateUI
}
}};

IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener onPurchaseFinishedListener=new  OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) 
        {
if (result.isFailure()) 
            {
                if(result.getResponse() == 7)
                {
                    complain("You have successfully restored");
                }
                return;
            }


        }
    };
```

Please provide me any help where i am wrong.

Comment: Can you specify that you are getting a Dialog of inappp purchase or not, if yes than is the purchase successfully completed or you are getting some error before you jump to transaction.

Comment: yes i am getting dialog of inapp purchase and i can buy successfully.

Comment: Ok so that means you are getting a callback in onPurchaseFinishedListener if yes than what was the value of purchase and result params

Comment: when I buy first time it does not go to the onPurchaseFinishedListener.

Comment: when I try to buy second time with same account then it goes in onPurchaseFinishListener.

Comment: and what was the value of of params in second time because it totally depends on what you get there.

Comment: Second time i get response 7 already owned item.